# How do I make the slab stable?

Tags: slab

The tiles/slabs I have outside my house are loose. So when I walk over them and step on the sides, the opposite side lifts up and its very awkward and dangerous. I would like to fix it properly on the ground. Please could any one tell whats the standard practice of fixing this type of issue. I have attached an image to show what i mean

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to:

- Pick up all of the tiles
- Excavate a few inches under where they were
- Put some small gravel down and compact
- Put some paver sand down and compact
- Reinstall the tiles

Another way to go would be to lay a bed of mortar down over some gravel.  That would lock them in really nicely as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto RQDQ.

Use dirty shale underneath the paver sand as the base - or pick up a couple bags of paver base from a local hardware store. You can use shale dust instead of the sand as well. You can use Polymeric paver sand to lock the pavers in place instead of messing with mortar also.

You simply dump this sand into the spaces between pavers, sweep away excess, and then very lightly mist water over the sand. As soon as the sand gets wet, it hardens and locks the pavers.

You have to re-level them. Your problem is they are not level.